# Deploy Laravel project in server without changing the public folder path

Tags: laravel, deployment, laravel-8, liveserver

**I have found a solution for laravel Deployment**
Most of us are stucked in the laravel deployment in server, most reason is changing the public path and modified the server.php

Please find the answer below:-

Answer (score 2):

Just Change the .htaccess and the problem is solved:

Change Two files in root 1.**.htaccess**, 2. **.index.php**

And Change Two files in public folder 1.**.htaccess**, 2. **.index.php**

> **Root Folder**
>
> > .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

> **Root Folder**
>
> > index.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
/*if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}*/
require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

> **Public Folder**
>
> > .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

> **Public Folder**
>
> > index.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command
| we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

*Find the solution and cheers...*
*Happy Coding..*

Comment: This doesn't work man.